# Custom Exceptions and type specs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, dialyzer

In elixir you can define a custom exception like this:

```
defmodule AppWeb.CustomError do
  defexception message: "some custom server error", plug_status: 500
end
```

But this is not an `Elixir.Exception` anymore

So if you use it with a third party library which has this kind of type spec defined:

```
  @spec capture_exception(Exception.t, Keyword.t) :: task
  def capture_exception(exception, opts \\ []) do

  ...

  Sentry.capture_exception(AppWeb.CustomError,
                         [stacktrace: System.stacktrace()]
```

The `dialyzer` will crash with `breaks the contract` because the CustomError is not an Exception:

> The call
>   'Elixir.Sentry':capture_exception('Elixir.AppWeb.CustomError',[{'stacktrace',[{atom(),atom(),[any()]
>   | byte(),[{'file',string()} | {'line',pos_integer()}]}]},...]) breaks
>   the contract ('Elixir.Exception':t(),'Elixir.Keyword':t()) -> task()

Can you somehow extend `Elixir.Exception` module within `AppWeb.CustomError`? or how can this be taken care following best practices?

Comment: Does `Sentry.capture_exception(%AppWeb.CustomError{}, ...) ` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the module name (`AppWeb.CustomError`) instead of an instance of it (`%AppWeb.CustomError{}`). An instance of the module will satisfy the `Exception.t` type.

```
Sentry.capture_exception(%AppWeb.CustomError{},
                         [stacktrace: System.stacktrace()]
```